# $\frac{a}{a+2b+c}+\frac{b}{b+2c+a}+\frac{c}{c+2a+b}\geq\frac{3}{4}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

I found the following exercise:
Prove that
$$\frac{a}{a+2b+c}+\frac{b}{b+2c+a}+\frac{c}{c+2a+b}\geq\frac{3}{4}$$
for any positive $a$, $b$, $c$.

I tried substituting the denominators but it led me nowhere. I don really have other ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$ \left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{a^2+2ab+ca}\right)\left[\sum_{cyc}(a^2+2ab+ca)\right] \geq \left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+2ab+ca}}\cdot \sqrt{a^2+2ab+ca}\right)^2$$

$$=(a+b+c)^2$$

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{cyc}(a^2+2ab+ca) =a^2+b^2+c^2+3(ab+bc+ca)$, we get:

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{a^2+2ab+ca}\geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2+3(ab+bc+ca)}$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{a+2b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{a^2+2ab+ca}\geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2+3(ab+bc+ca)}$$

It remains to prove:

$$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2+3(ab+bc+ca)} \geq \frac{3}{4}$$

or after expanding

$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$$

which is

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\right]\geq 0$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate the first step?

Comment: @HowardDickson, I added some detail. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Thank you, its much better now for young students

Answer (score 2):

A full expanding gives $$\sum_{cyc}(2a^3-a^2b+3a^2c-4abc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b)+\sum_{cyc}(a^3+3a^2c-4abc)\geq0,$$ which is true by Rearrangement and AM-GM.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?

Comment: Maybe,due to the incomplete answer.

Comment: @Howard Dickson I am ready to explain, how I made expanding. It's just five minutes of work with a cyclic sums. Do you want to see it?

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: @Howard Dickson What do you mean?